# How to center scrollable contents on a div with dynamic height?

Tags: html, css, web-applications

I'm making a web app, and currently I'm trying to get the basic design done.
So there should be a few columns  on the page that should be able to float on the x-axis. They are for now static in width, and the height of them is going to be 100 % of the browser window. Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qAUXQ/

Inside these columns, there should be contents that is centered vertically. However, if the contents of one column is higher than the browser window, there should appear a scroll bar. The problem is that since the height is dynamical, the only way I can think of (and find on Google) is to use the `display: table` method.

The problem is that the scrollbars on the div doesn't work. So when the browser window is too small, the user simply cannot see it. It's not scrollable!

Below is the code if you don't want to use JSFiddle:

```
<div class="bar">
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="contents">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

body {
    background: #f4f1ed;
}

.bar {
    height: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 360px;
    display: table;
    border-width: 0 1px;
    border-color: #ddd;
    position: absolute;
    transition: left 500ms;
    -moz-transition: left 500ms;
    -webkit-transition: left 500ms;
    -o-transition: left 500ms;
    z-index: 10;
    background: #f2f2f2;
}

.bar div.middle {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.bar div.contents {
    padding-left: 60px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I figured it out finally. It was a pretty easy task, I just didn't see it. Just like you never find what you are looking for if it's right in front of your nose...

Answer (score 1):

Having a bit of a time understanding precisely what you're asking.  But from what I'm gathering, you may want to try adding a height and using

```
overflow:scroll;
```

**EDIT (updated)**

Had to shuffle it around a bit, but this works:

```
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: #f4f1ed;
}
.bar {
    height: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 360px;
    border-width: 0 1px;
    border-color: #ddd;
    position: absolute;
    transition: left 500ms;
    -moz-transition: left 500ms;
    -webkit-transition: left 500ms;
    -o-transition: left 500ms;
    z-index: 10;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    overflow:scroll;
}
.bar div.middle {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.bar div.contents {
    padding-left: 60px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Can check out http://jsfiddle.net/qAUXQ/7/ for the full solution (updated)

Reupdated for the centering.  Wanting to use table and table-cell in the direction you were going.  Checked it out with minor list and it centers, longer list, it scrolls.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I've done. But as you can see from the JSFiddle, the scrollbars don't activate. They are just grayed out, and that's because the div is `display: table-cell`. But I can't figure out any other way to center a div with dynamic height..

Comment: How is the height being defined?  If I lock down your fiddle with a set height, the scrollbars work fine.

Comment: Which browser? The height is defined by the amount of text/pictures inside the column (div).

Comment: The scrollbars on the `body`works fine, but the scrollbars on the div doesn't work at all.

Comment: You are going to have to define a height for the div.middle container at some point.  Using "height:100%" is just going to make the container grow with the content.  Once you do that, it works, see http://jsfiddle.net/qAUXQ/1/.

Comment: Yes, I know. But this isn't solving my problem. I'm making a web app which is going to have menus of variable heights..

Comment: What defines the variable?  Sorry, guess I'm still just a little confused on what you are shooting for.

Comment: Okay, so I have this div that spans the height of the browser. Now, if  there is enough text to cover, lets say 50 %, this text will be centered vertically. If there is more text than can fit inside the div, there should be a scrollbar the user can use to show all the text inside this div..

Comment: Updated answer, that should do it for you. :)

Comment: I figured it out finally. It was a pretty easy task, I just didn't see it. Just like you never find what you are looking for if it's right in front of your nose...

Comment: So I'm going to share the solution :)

Comment: lol...sorry about that, was working on something then came back and tinkered.  Similar solutions looks like.  Glad you got it worked out though. Sometimes it's tough when you're so close to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I figured it out myself finally. It was pretty easy, but I was just "blind"...

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qAUXQ/6/

Just do it like this:

```
div bar
    div container
        div contents
            contents
```

Then you do some CSS:

```
.bar {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
    display: table;
}

.contents {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

What I did first was setting the .bar to `display: table`. So the scrollbar didn't work. Now the scrollbar is set on the .bar.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly what you are trying to do, when im not misstaken you want your .bar div to be 100% height with a scrollbar and your .middle and .contents in the vertical center. So just try changing the following things:

`.bar {display:block; overflow: auto; height: 100%; min-height:100%; width:100%;
}`

add a additional div tag for the display:table :

```
div.table{
height:100%;
border-style: solid;
width: 360px;
display: table;
border-width: 0 1px;
border-color: #ddd;
position: absolute;
transition: left 500ms;
-moz-transition: left 500ms;
-webkit-transition: left 500ms;
-o-transition: left 500ms;
z-index: 10;
background: #f2f2f2;}
```

You just use the rest of the two table elements for vertical and horizontal align. No overflow there.
Now you have 3 divs for setting up the table and one Div thats controlling the overflow and the scrollbar.

like this? http://jsfiddle.net/WAjdp/